# Convert wav to mp3

Tags: c#, .net, mono, converters

I try to convert a .wav file to a .mp3 file using C# and Mono.

I found [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8544/Aumplib-C-Namespace-And-Classes-For-Audio-Conversi) which might be helpful.

When I use the following code to convert, I miss a *libsndfile.dll*. So I searched my harddrive and found it, but using it I get the message that it is not a valid .NET assembly.

```
 AumpelWrapper wrapper = new AumpelWrapper ();
_wrapper.Convert (filePath, (int)SoundFormat.WAV, targetPath, (int)SoundFormat.MP3);
```

Is there another way to convert wav to mp3 or do I need another library, that this will work?

I want to use that in our company, so it needs to be OK with the license.

Comment: there is another very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899751/convert-wav-bytes-to-mp3

Comment: doesnt really work with mono. I tried using lame but till now, no success